# Page control switches page before completely going to the next page

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have created a page control for a collection view, each collection view cell is the height and width of the screen. 
Here is the setup of the page control:

```
// Setup the page control
func setupPageControl() {

    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = cellColor
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = themeColor

    view.addSubview(pageControl)
    addPageControlConstraints()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = collectionViewCellData.count
    return collectionViewCellData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
}
```

There is a small problem with the page control, check this out:

[image: Screen recording]

Notice how the page control changes when I haven't even completely gone to the next page, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: maybe you need scrollViewDidEndDecelerating? to handle scroll ended, or you can handle offset in scrollViewDidScroll to understand at which moment you want to change something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use UIPageViewControllerDelegate's method "didFinishAnimating: previousViewControllers: transitionCompleted:" and use the transitionCompleted boolean that helps you to update your page

OR

Refer this link to use [UIPageControl](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92)

Comment: Hey umm, I haven’t worked too much with page control but here, my class isn’t conforming to uipageviewcontroller I’m just using a page control like so ‘let pageControl = UIPageControl()’

Comment: Okay buddy look at the edited answer and refer that link.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, man, all I had to do was copy and paste lol.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply that you're setting the page control's currentPage in willDisplay cell, about which the documentation says:

> Tells the delegate that the specified cell is about to be displayed in the collection view.

This is a method which is called *before* the cell is displayed.

You should use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` for your purpose.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dhaval Raval, I found the answer in the link he had provided, here it is:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
```